# Create View SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a student this is homework.  I use SQL server to check my work but have to write script by hand.

> Create and display a VIEW that
>   displays the account balance subtotals
>   for each account group.  Account group
>   is defined as the first two digits of
>   the account number.  Display a grand
>   total of the balance column at the end
>   of the display.

I have one table with 4 columns. Account(numbers), Description, Short_Description, and Balance(money).  The Account numbers range from 100001-610003. COA is the chart of accounts that is an excel link. Thanks for any advice.

This is what I have so far...

```
CREATE VIEW [account_balance_sums]
 AS 
 SELECT Account, Short_Description,Balance
 FROM COA
 Where Account, (first two digits 10-61 of account #)
 AND sum
 GO

SELECT * FROM [account_balance_sums]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to do it for you as you will never learn but you will need the [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause.

Comment: Thanks... that is for grouping by the first 2 numbers of the account. How do I pick the first 2 numbers?

Comment: You will need a function, you can specify functions in the GROUP BY clause, have a think about it, give it a try and come back here if you get stuck. It will be different depending on the way the account number is stored, is it a VARCHAR or a INT.

Comment: Yes, you can specify non-aggregate functions in the GROUP BY clause.  `GROUP BY LEFT(account, 2)` works for me on SQL Server 2005...

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is homework I just want to give you enough to get going, but it seems to me that you want to do something like

```
SELECT ...., SUM(Balance) as group_subtotal, SUBSTRING(Account,0,2) AS account_group
FROM ....
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Account,0,2), ...
```

Comment: is there a benefit to use SUBSTRING instead of LEFT?

Comment: No, LEFT makes sense in this context.  For a student, if you're only going to learn one command, SUBSTRING is good to understand as it is more general.

Comment: You need to correct the GROUP BY - it won't return an error, but the sum won't reflect the LEFT/SUBSTRING for grouping - you'll get a row for each group.

Comment: He's actually grouping by the alias (which isn't allowed in SQL Server)

Comment: @Tom yes that is correct, it's worth noting that you can `ORDER BY` an alias.

Answer (score 1):

So, GROUP BY and SUM will get you most of the way. Then use WITH CUBE/ROLLUP to get the grand total. You may want to look into the GROUPING() function if you go this route.

Comment: Thanks looking into that cube rollup

Here is what I have so far...


CREATE VIEW [account_balance_sums]
AS
    SELECT SUM(balance) AS total,
           SUBSTRING(Account,0,2) AS account_group
      FROM COA
  GROUP BY account_group
  
GO

SELECT * FROM [account_balance_sums]

Comment: Does that work? you need to put your SUBSTRING function in the GROUP BY i'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I don't want to give it away, but you'll need to add up the balances, so you'll need to use the `SUM` function.

Also, since you want to `SUM` them by the first two digits of the account number, you'll need to use `GROUP BY` to create the groups, and `SUBSTR` to get the first two digits.

Exactly how you put it all together is the real trick of course.